# How to organize files in folders?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory

I have this script that currently works partially.

**Step 1 (working):**
More precisely, it groups all my `.mp4` files found in the directory. I choose the number of `.mp4` files in each folder. So far all good.

**Step 2 (not working):**
When I try to move the folders created together with the MP4 files inside and group them by 15 or as many as I need, I can't find the optimal solution.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
PushD %~dp0
set "filesInfolder=60"
set "foldersInfolders=15"
set "fcount=0"
set "fcounta=0"
set idx=0
set idxa=0

REM here all the .mp4 files will be grouped 60 in each folder

for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /a-d /o:n /b *.mp4') do (
    REM echo Processing %%I
    set /a idx=idx %% filesinfolder +1
    if !idx! equ 1 set /a fcount+=1
    md Videos-!fcount! 2>nul
    move "%%I" "Videos-!fcount!\"
) 

REM here I need the folders created together with the .mp4 files to be grouped by 15 in other folders.

for /D "delims=" %%A in (*.*) do  (
    REM echo Processing %%A
    set /Y idxa=idxa %% foldersinfolders +1
    if !idxa! equ 1 set /a fcounta+=1
    md Canal-!fcounta! 2>nul
    move "%%~fA" "Canal-!fcounta!\"
)
```

Everything happens in a loop until all the `.mp4` files are moved.

Comment: What is `Set /Y`? `;)`

Comment: @Gerhard Thank you for answering. I took the information from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/batch_script_moving_folders.htm  I tried all kinds of options, hoping to find a solution  :(

Comment: ok, there is not such a switch for `set` you'll see all available switches by running `set /?` from `cmd`. anyway, `for /D` does not use `delims=` only `/F` does. so do `for /D %%A in (*.*) do  (` and remove `/Y` from `set` and resplace with `/a`

Comment: `I tried all kinds of options` - Guessing valid options for a command is suboptimal at best. Better ask the command itself, which switches it supports, like `set /?`. I recommend to bookmark (and visit often) [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/)

Comment: @Gerhard initially it was set /a, but I kept twisting the code until I wrote something stupid and I didn't notice it afterwards. Thank you already! I'm getting closer to solving the problem. :)

Comment: Did you remove `delims=` from `for /D` as well?

Comment: @Gerhard I did it, it works. I will post the final solution here. But I want to optimize it. How can I move the folders in order by name? Videos1 Videos2 etc. Now it is moved randomly, 15 in each folder.

Comment: @Gerhard something else is happening! Not very often.. about once in 20 executions or even more. 1 folder is missing in one of the folders. instead of 15 I have 14 folders. But very rarely it happens to miss. Is there any way to prevent any possibility of it happening again? The truth is that the script is very fast, I have 7000 files... in 3-4 seconds it's ready. Is it because of the speed that it re-creates a folder from time to time?

Comment: @Stephan Wow, this site is very helpful. thank you so much.  :)

Comment: Unfortunately I am not at my PC and posting from my mobile, so not easy to post working code, but firstly, no, it is not because of the speed. It is best to incorporate both processes into a single `for` loop and hen do it all in one go. i.e order, take a file set, move them to a folder and move that folder to its parent. This way you are also moving the folders in the order they are created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be used the following batch file to organize the video files in directory of the batch file by moving them to dynamically created directories as long as no MP4 file contains an exclamation mark in file name.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
pushd "%~dp0"
if not exist "*!*.mp4" goto MoveFiles
echo ERROR: Moving video files not possible because of file names with ! in name.
echo(
echo Please rename first the following files(s):
echo(
dir *!*.mp4 /A-D /B
echo(
pause
goto EndBatch

:MoveFiles
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "FilesInFolder=60"
set "FoldersInFolders=15"
set "FileCount=%FilesInFolder%"
set "CanalIndex=0"
set "VideosIndex=%FoldersInFolders%
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir *.mp4 /A-D /B /ON 2^>nul') do (
    if !FileCount! == %FilesInFolder% (
        set FileCount=0
        if !VideosIndex! == %FoldersInFolders% (
            set /A CanalIndex+=1
            set VideosIndex=1
        ) else set /A VideosIndex+=1
        set "TargetFolder=Canal-!CanalIndex!\Videos-!VideosIndex!"
        md "!TargetFolder!" 2>nul
    )
    move /Y "%%I" "!TargetFolder!\" >nul
    set /A FileCount+=1
)
endlocal

:EndBatch
popd
endlocal
```

The environment variable `TargetFolder` with the two dynamic changed numbers `CanalIndex` and `VideosIndex` can be further modified to the wanted format.

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

Please note that the ordering of the MP4 files by name caused by option `/ON` by command **DIR** is strictly alphabetic and not natural alphanumeric. The command line executed by **FOR** by starting one more `cmd.exe` in background with option `/c` and the command line appended as argument string(s) could be modified to get MP4 file names output and so processed next in a different order.

Example of the **FOR** command line with moving MP4 files with the file names `file (1).mp4`, ... `file (9).mp4`, `file (10).mp4`, ... `file (99).mp4`, `file (100).mp4`, ... `file (999).mp4`, `file (1000).mp4`, ... `file (9999).mp4`:

```
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir *.mp4 /A-D /B /ON 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R "([0-9])\.mp4$" ^& dir *.mp4 /A-D /B /ON 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R "([0-9][0-9])\.mp4$" ^& dir *.mp4 /A-D /B /ON 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R "([0-9][0-9][0-9])\.mp4$" ^& dir *.mp4 /A-D /B /ON 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R "([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])\.mp4$"') do (
```

Please note that `[0-9]` matches also the characters `¹²³` which should be no problem here.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `move /?`
- `pause /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

---

Extended version to process MP4 files in multiple directories specified in the first **FOR** loop instead of the batch file directory:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "FilesInFolder=60"
set "FoldersInFolders=15"
for %%# in ("%USERPROFILE%\Videos" "D:\Videos" "F:\Temp\Videos" "\\MyNAS\Videos") do (
    pushd %%# 2>nul
    if not errorlevel 1 (
        if not exist "*!*.mp4" (
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            set "FileCount=%FilesInFolder%"
            set "CanalIndex=0"
            set "VideosIndex=%FoldersInFolders%
            for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir *.mp4 /A-D /B /ON 2^>nul') do (
                if !FileCount! == %FilesInFolder% (
                    set FileCount=0
                    if !VideosIndex! == %FoldersInFolders% (
                        set /A CanalIndex+=1
                        set VideosIndex=1
                    ) else set /A VideosIndex+=1
                    set "TargetFolder=Canal-!CanalIndex!\Videos-!VideosIndex!"
                    md "!TargetFolder!" 2>nul
                )
                move /Y "%%I" "!TargetFolder!\" >nul
                set /A FileCount+=1
            )
            endlocal
        ) else (
            echo(
            echo ERROR: Moving video files not possible because of file names with ! in name.
            echo(
            echo Please rename first the following files(s^) in: %%#
            echo(
            dir *!*.mp4 /A-D /B
            echo(
            pause
        )
        popd
    ) else (
        echo(
        echo ERROR: Failed to change to directory: %%#
        echo(
        pause
    )
)
endlocal
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work. I am attaching the version of the code in this form and I will also come up with a version with a single `for` loop.

If someone wants to optimize this solution, it is free and I really encourage it. Thank you very much!

**UPDATE:** I made an optimized version. Thanks to @Mofi

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
pushd "%~dp0"
set "filesInfolder=60"
set "foldersInfolders=15"
set "fcount=0"
set "fcounta=0"
set idx=0
set idxa=0

 
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /a-d /o:n /b *.mp4') do (
    REM echo Processing %%I
    set /a idx=idx %% filesinfolder +1
    if !idx! == 1 set /a fcount+=1
    md Videos-!fcount! 2>nul
    move "%%I" "Videos-!fcount!\"

  ) 
 
for /D %%A in (*.*) do  (
    REM echo Processing %%A
    set /a idxa=idxa %% foldersinfolders +1
    if !idxa! == 1 set /a fcounta+=1
    md Canal-!fcounta! 2>nul
    move "%%~fA" "Canal-!fcounta!\"

  
)
endlocal
```

Later edit:

Now the directories ordered alphabetically by name.
`Videos-1, Videos-10, Videos-11, ... Video-19`
I need them in a natural alphanumeric order

I found a temporary solution that renames all my internal folders in a row, but at the end I will explain in a folder structure how will be more nice for me to be.

I just modified:

```
md Videos-!fcount! 2>nul
move "%%I" "Videos-!fcount!\"
```

and made it

```
md Videos-!fcount!-123 2>nul
move "%%I" "Videos-!fcount!-123\"
```

I have the files in **MP4-files** folder

```
───MP4-files Folder
│   ├───file.mp4 - (1)
│   ├───file.mp4 - (10)
│   ├───file.mp4 - (11)
│   ├───file.mp4 - (2)
│   ├───file.mp4 - (3)
│   ├───file.mp4 - (4)
│   ├───file.mp4 - (5)
│   ├───file.mp4 - (6)
│   ├───file.mp4 - (7)
│   ├───file.mp4 - (8)
│   └───file.mp4 - (9)
```

Here I run the batch file above (with that small modification `-123` )
and all .mp4 files are moved first in Videos-1, Videos-2 ... Videos- xx , depends how many .mp4 files I have in folder.
Each of the Videos folders have mp4 files in it (deppends how many I wrote in script) `set "filesInfolder=60"`  is now, but can be different.

After that the folders Videos-1 .. Videos-xx are grouped in other folders with the name of "Canal-1 .. Canal-10 .. Canal-x" in order. the number of folders deppends on how many Videos folders. How many I group is here `set "foldersInfolders=15"` can be 15 or other number.

I get this:

```
─MP4-files Folder
│       ├───Canal-1 ->  (set "foldersInfolders=15")
│       │   ├───Videos-1-123  (inside are the .mp4 files) -> set "filesInfolder=60"
│       │   ├───Videos-10-123
│       │   ├───Videos-100-123
│       │   ├───Videos-101-123
│       │   ├───Videos-102-123
│       │   ├───Videos-103-123
│       │   ├───Videos-104-123
│       │   ├───Videos-105-123
│       │   ├───Videos-106-123
│       │   ├───Videos-107-123
│       │   ├───Videos-108-123
│       │   ├───Videos-109-123
│       │   ├───Videos-11-123
│       │   ├───Videos-110-123
│       │   └───Videos-111-123
│       ├───Canal-2
│       │   ├───Videos-12-123
│       │   ├───Videos-13-123
│       │   ├───Videos-14-123
│       │   ├───Videos-15-123
│       │   ├───Videos-16-123
│       │   ├───Videos-17-123
│       │   ├───Videos-18-123
│       │   ├───Videos-19-123
│       │   ├───Videos-2-123
│       │   ├───Videos-20-123
│       │   ├───Videos-21-123
│       │   ├───Videos-22-123
│       │   ├───Videos-23-123
│       │   ├───Videos-24-123
│       │   └───Videos-25-123
│       ├───Canal-3
│       │   ├───Videos-26-123
│       │   ├───Videos-27-123
│       │   ├───Videos-28-123
│       │   ├───Videos-29-123
│       │   ├───Videos-3-123
│       │   ├───Videos-30-123
│       │   ├───Videos-31-123
│       │   ├───Videos-32-123
│       │   ├───Videos-33-123
│       │   ├───Videos-34-123
│       │   ├───Videos-35-123
│       │   ├───Videos-36-123
│       │   ├───Videos-37-123
│       │   ├───Videos-38-123
│       │   └───Videos-39-123
```

Then I run the following batch file:

```
@Echo off
  
set Cnt=0
for /f "delims=" %%A in (
  'dir /B /S /AD Videos-* ^| findstr /iV "^Videos-[0-9][0-9]*$" '
) Do Call :RenInc "%%A"
PopD    
Goto :Eof

:RenInc
Set /A Cnt+=1
if Exist "Videos-%Cnt%" goto :RenInc
Ren "%~1" "Videos-%Cnt%"
```

and I get the following folder structure:

```
──Video-15-sec
│       ├───Canal-1
│       │   ├───Videos-1
│       │   ├───Videos-2
│       │   ├───Videos-3
│       │   ├───Videos-4
│       │   ├───Videos-5
│       │   ├───Videos-6
│       │   ├───Videos-7
│       │   ├───Videos-8
│       │   ├───Videos-9
│       │   ├───Videos-10
│       │   ├───Videos-11
│       │   ├───Videos-12
│       │   ├───Videos-13
│       │   ├───Videos-14
│       │   └───Videos-15
│       ├───Canal-2
│       │   ├───Videos-16
│       │   ├───Videos-17
│       │   ├───Videos-18
│       │   ├───Videos-19
│       │   ├───Videos-20
│       │   ├───Videos-21
│       │   ├───Videos-22
│       │   ├───Videos-23
│       │   ├───Videos-24
│       │   ├───Videos-25
│       │   ├───Videos-26
│       │   ├───Videos-27
│       │   ├───Videos-28
│       │   ├───Videos-29
│       │   └───Videos-30
│       ├───Canal-3
│       │   ├───Videos-31
│       │   ├───Videos-32
│       │   ├───Videos-33
│       │   ├───Videos-34
│       │   ├───Videos-35
│       │   ├───Videos-36
│       │   ├───Videos-37
│       │   ├───Videos-38
│       │   ├───Videos-39
│       │   ├───Videos-40
│       │   ├───Videos-41
│       │   ├───Videos-42
│       │   ├───Videos-43
│       │   ├───Videos-44
│       │   └───Videos-45
│       ├───Canal-4
```

It is nice, but more nice for me if i can get the following folder structure after I run 1 single time the first Batch file attached in this Answer.

```
──Video-15-sec
│       ├───Canal-1
│       │   ├───Videos-1
│       │   ├───Videos-2
│       │   ├───Videos-3
│       │   ├───Videos-4
│       │   ├───Videos-5
│       │   ├───Videos-6
│       │   ├───Videos-7
│       │   ├───Videos-8
│       │   ├───Videos-9
│       │   ├───Videos-10
│       │   ├───Videos-11
│       │   ├───Videos-12
│       │   ├───Videos-13
│       │   ├───Videos-14
│       │   └───Videos-15
│       ├───Canal-2
│       │   ├───Videos-1
│       │   ├───Videos-2
│       │   ├───Videos-3
│       │   ├───Videos-4
│       │   ├───Videos-5
│       │   ├───Videos-6
│       │   ├───Videos-7
│       │   ├───Videos-8
│       │   ├───Videos-9
│       │   ├───Videos-10
│       │   ├───Videos-11
│       │   ├───Videos-12
│       │   ├───Videos-13
│       │   ├───Videos-14
│       │   └───Videos-15
│       ├───Canal-3
│       │   ├───Videos-1
│       │   ├───Videos-2
│       │   ├───Videos-3
│       │   ├───Videos-4
│       │   ├───Videos-5
│       │   ├───Videos-6
│       │   ├───Videos-7
│       │   ├───Videos-8
│       │   ├───Videos-9
│       │   ├───Videos-10
│       │   ├───Videos-11
│       │   ├───Videos-12
│       │   ├───Videos-13
│       │   ├───Videos-14
│       │   └───Videos-15
│       ├───Canal-4
```

Thank you a lot